# Django given URL path name get URL

Tags: python, django, url

I am trying to create a view which will list the URLs available on the server.

given a url path like so:

```
path(r'reindex_search', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='reindex')
```

How can I, from within views.py, get the full path (eg 'http://localhost:8000/reindex_search'), given the name 'reindex'?

I have tried using rest_framework.reverse and it works for some of my endpoints but fails on the urls that have variables in the path. Here is my attempt so far:

urls.py

```
api_root_dict = OrderedDict()
...
api_root_dict['reindex_search'] = 'reindex'
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(r'reindex_search', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='reindex'),
    path('api/', views.HomeView.as_view(api_root_dict=api_root_dict), name='home'),
    ...
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(APIView):
    api_root_dict = None 

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        ret = OrderedDict()

        namespace = request.resolver_match.namespace

        for key, url_name in self.api_root_dict.items():
            if namespace:
                url_name = namespace + ":" + url_name
            try:
                ret[key] = {
                        'href': reverse(
                            url_name,
                            args=args,
                            kwargs=kwargs,
                            request=request,
                            format=kwargs.get('format', None)
                            )
                        }
            except NoReverseMatch:
                continue 

        home_url = reverse(viewname='home', request=request)

        obj = {
                '_links': {
                    'self': {"href": home_url},
                    **ret
                    }
                }

        return Response(obj)
```

This fails for example for the following path in my *app's* urls.py:

```
path('<str:endpoint>/schema', views.schema, name='schema')
```

with this in added to the root dict:

```
api_root_dict['schema'] = 'schema'
```

(by fail I mean NoReverseMatch exception)

There must be a better way. How does Django templates do it with the url keywork??

Comment: Why search via a custom dictionary (api_root_dict) and not just all of urlpatterns?

Comment: yes good point.

Comment: You get the reverse match fail because the path requires arguments and you don't provide the exact amount of arguments. You could however regex parse the paths (that's what Django does as well) and then determine the number of arguments required, so that you can provide a valid reverse call.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse as api_reverse


class HomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = {
            "api": {
                "search_api":  api_reverse("reindex", request=request),
            },

        }
        return Response(data)
```